# Wordpress - Chrome / Safari issues with font size and image layout

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, compatibility

I'm having some cross browser styling issues with a site I've just loaded up onto a wordpress html5blank child theme.

For example, here's an image layout as it is showing in Chrome -

[image: staff img - block stack]

And this is in Firefox & Safari (how it should look) -

[image: staff img - inline-block]

The style code is set correctly as `display: inline-block;` but Chrome isn't having it.

I also have issues in Safari and Chrome regarding font-weight (showing much lighter than is set) and font-size (smaller than it should be). Is there some method and/or plugin that stops all the compatibility issues?

UPDATE -

I've placed the code on a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/MikeWhitehead/pen/BwvOqz)

Comment: can i see online link ?

Comment: @SanjayPrajapati To what, the site? It's still on localhost.

Comment: oh @Mike.Whitehead  i will check  after solution

Comment: Can you replicate in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @msbodetti I've added a codepen link to the answer. It might be the masonry column rule but why would it only do it on chrome and not safari and firefox?

Comment: It is odd @Mike.Whitehead but change .brick `display:inline-block` to `display:flex`

Comment: @msbodetti No, it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Hmm odd. It should have changed, see this forked pen https://codepen.io/msbodetti/pen/JrwmXQ

Comment: @msbodetti The only conclusion, then is that it is a compatibility issue specific to wordpress. How do I get all my child - theme styles to apply? Is there a plugin or something for compatibility?

Comment: See here > https://digwp.com/2016/01/include-styles-child-theme/

Comment: @msbodetti So, I go for the disabling parent theme option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add

```
.brick { float: left;}
```

I tested it in your code pen, and when I inspected the element float: left; was greyed out for some reason.  Then I just added the above to your code, and it worked.

Add this to target firefox

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .brick {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for Chrome and Safari but breaks on Firefox.

Comment: Okay I've ammended the answer to include float: none; targeted only at firefox browsers

Comment: Thanks Colin, I've marked your answer correct. Do I always use that prefix then to target firefox with a bespoke CSS rule? How do I target Chrome and/or Safari ? It might help me with this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46814877/3521315

Comment: Thanks @Mike.Whitehead 
You shouldn't always need to use that prefix only when you have conflict issues.

Comment: for Chrome and Safari I believe this would work 

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{ 
    .brick { float: left; } 
}

Comment: Note these are css hacks just for conflict issues, and not for general coding

Comment: Many thanks. I've just got a few issues with some text - it looks as though I need some more font files but not sure if the client has them so this 'might' give me a work around:)

Answer (score 2):

With some help from the responses to this, I figured it out -

```
.staff .brick {
       display: flex;

}
```